# order by changing count () over (partition by ) result set

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get count of some transaction types happened on each individual day at some locations. for example if i have two different types of transactions x,y and a date and a location (NY), im trying to see for that date and for that location how many transactions of x happened, how many transactions of y happened and a grand total. Looks good but when i use order by date desc the results change and all locations for same dates have same counts. Can someone throw some light here as to why this is happening. 
For different location and same dates i'm getting same counts.

i used the logic below

```
select location, trunc(date),
       count(location) over (partition by date) as grand_total 
from table
where transaction_types in (x,y)
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

expected results should be:

```
locaton       date         grandtotal
NY          1/1/2019          5
NJ          1/1/2019          7
```

ACTUAL

```
LOCATION     DATE         GRANDTOTAL
NY          1/1/2019        5
NJ          1/1/2019        5
```

For different location and same dates i'm getting same counts.

Comment: Posting some source data would be helpful.  If you `partition by date`, you should get the same result for each date regardless of any `order by` in your outer query.  My guess is that you want `count(*) over (partition by location)` assuming you actually want an analytic function rather than an aggregate function with a `group by` in your query

Comment: Several logical mistakes there. If you need TRUNC(DATE), that means DATE (terrible name for a column, as it is the name of a data type in Oracle) has time-of-day component. If you want to count all transactions for a given date, you should partition by TRUNC(DATE), not by DATE. Then: if you want to count transactions by location, why are you counting LOCATION? LOCATION should be in PARTITION BY, along with TRUNC(DATE). The count should be of transactions, and conditional on transaction type: `COUNT(CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'x' THEN 1 END) OVER .....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following query which uses `group by` and conditional `aggregate` function will solve your problem:

```
select location, 
trunc(date), 
Sum(case when transaction_types = 'x' then 1 end) as x_total,
Sum(case when transaction_types = 'y' then 1 end) as y_total,
count(1) as total
from table where transaction_types in (x,y)
group by location,trunc(date);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: I added nvl to individual transaction counts to put 0 where there were no transactions and left blank. Thanks again.

Comment: The result will be different if `location` also contain NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

Just add location in your partition by as you want to have datewise for each location not just datewise only hence partitioning should be done with location included with date

```
     select location, trunc(date), 
     count(location) 
    over (partition by location, date) as 
    grand_total 
    from table where transaction_types in 
    (x,y)
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```